# How can I replace some of the values with a null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I replace the unequal columns in a table with a `Null` value when the table was created with no null values?

Example

```
employeeid   city         home
----------------------------------------
1            munich       augsburg
|    
\--in this case employeeid and city should show a 'null' value
```

Can I use outer join when I combine 2 tables? Or Inner Join?

I cannot use insert as the table was created without using insert.

Comment: Updating you table, to make it possible to set `employeeid` to a NULL value, is not be possible when this is the primary key of that table.   Under normal circumstances you should never need to update a primary key value in a table.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Presumably your column, `employeeid` is your Primary Key, and as @Luuk mentioned, though you can have a PK with the value `NULL` you could only have **one** row with that value (and I suspect you have more than one row). Also your statement *"I cannot use insert as the table was created without using insert."* doesn't make sense; you don't use `INSERT` to `CREATE` a table anyway.

Comment: "unequal columns" what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear with your question but you have to set column attribute nullable first then you can set it  through query.

```
update tablename set employeeid=null,city=null where column=checkvalue
```